# Can I use custom web font in facebook instant articles?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I try to use custom web font in my markup. Can I use font which I use in my web page different from fonts in  style editor "Helvetica, Georgia".

I think this publishers use their own fonts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhOue.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYDew.jpg

www.i.stack.imgur.com/FDbnh.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response from Facebook "It's not an available option at the moment." 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1121715027891936/

Answer (score 1):

there are stylesheet links in facebook’s instant article example articles:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://instantarticles.fb.com/example3">
    <link rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="#">
    <title>Using Captions in Instant Articles</title>
    <meta property="fb:article_style" content="Test Article Style">
  </head>
```

the publishers above probably use stylesheets of their own. i tried putting some font definitions in a stylesheet and added it to my instant pages RSS template, but it didn’t work. without proper documentation there’s probably no other way than trial and error.